# RabbitMQ Message Lifetime Replay Message

Tags: rabbitmq

We are currently evaluating RabbitMQ.  Trying to determine how best to implement some of our processes as Messaging apps instead of traditional DB store and grab.  Here is the scenario.  We have a department of users who perform similar tasks.  As they submit work to the server applications we would like the server app to send messages back into a notification window saying what was done - to all the users, not just the one submitting the work.  This is all easy to do.

The question is we would like these message to live for say 4 hours in the Queue.  If a new user logs in or say a supervisor they would get all the messages from the last 4 hours delivered to their notification window.  This gives them a quick way to review what has recently happened and what is going on without having to ask others, "have you talked to John?", "Did you email him is itinerary?", etc.

So, how do we publish messages that have a lifetime of x hours from the time they were published AND any new consumers that connect will get all of these messages delivered in chronological order?  And preferably the messages just disappear after they have expired from the queue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Per-Queue Message TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-queue-message-ttl) and [Per-Message TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl) in RabbitMQ. If I am right you can utilize them for your task.

Comment: This isn't good enough on its own.  Each user would need a durable queue created a priori so that the messages were there waiting for the user to pick up.  Otherwise once a message is read how is a new user logging on going to see his previous messages.

Comment: I see no problems to have per-user queues and publish messages to them.

Comment: It would depend on how many users there are. But I only added it as you hadn't mentioned it.

Comment: So I understand the comments and a per user queue could make sense as there would not be that many users.  However, the issue is if the user's pc were to crash or they logged off for lunch, when they restart the app, there will be no messages in their notification window.  Ideal would be to get the message but not acknowledge the get, but can you do this and still get the other messages too?  Basically, letting RabbitMQ manage the lifetime of these messages with the per Message TTL.

Comment: Don't worry about users and messages number - RabbitMQ will take care about it. As to keeping messages in queue after they are delivered: definitely, you can do that. But it looks like AMQP (and Message Queues in general) is inappropriate technology here, i guess typical relational database, like MySQL fits well here. KISS.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, it would be better to have the application/client publish messages to two queues. Consumer would consume from one of the queues while the other queue can be configured using per queue-message TTL or per message TTL to retain the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Queuing messages you do to get a message from one point to the other reliable. So the sender can work independently from the receiver. What you propose is working with a temporary persistent store.

A sql database would fit perfectly, but also a mongodb would work nicely. You drop a document in mongo, give it a ttl and let the database handle the expiration.

http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/expire-data/